# Why does my animated character rig move only in one direction, and repositioning or rotation does not effect the animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

I made a rig on blender, exported to fbx (mesh & armature), input it in mixamo, downloaded animated fbx from mixamo, and imported back the animation as fbx. But for some reason, the animation has a fixed location to move. If i move the armature or armature with objects to other location and start the animation, the rig moves back to the original position, where it was first imported.

Earlier i only put blender object into mixamo and mixamo generated the rig. The resulting fbx was easy to rotate or reposition. I am not sure if having my own rig from blender is causing this issue. Pleas help how can i rotate/position this animation anywhere in the viewport.

Comment: P.S.: For some reason, when i try to import fbx and save file as .blend file to upload to blend-exchange, it gives me error- All uploaded files must be in the blend file format. So, I have uploaded it below - https://easyupload.io/w1mnwp

Comment: It moves, undoing your transformations whenever you change frame, because the armature object is keyframed.  These keyframes were probably generated by Mixamo, although I don't use it.  If you'd like to create a simple offset to the existing animation, parent your armature to an empty and move that empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried that and it works. Is there any way i can remove those specific keyframes from armature object?

Comment: Yes. Select armature object, open graph editor, delete all location, rotation, and scale keyframes for the armature object-- the channels that don't have any bone in parentheses after them.  There are nine different channels to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it out.